# How to get access to the functions from a module

Tags: vb.net, reflection

I need to get access to the public functions in a module (not a class).  This is what I have tried:

```
    Dim asm As Reflection.Assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly
    Dim my_modules = asm.GetModules
    For Each my_module In my_modules
        Dim all_methods = my_module.GetMethods
        Stop
    Next
```

But that doesn't even get down to the module itself, I just get the name of the executable.

Comment: A vb.net module is not the same as a .net assembly module. Afaik a vb.net module compiles to a normal .net type. So you have to use something like `Assembly.GetTypes()` and search from there.

Comment: That `GetModules` method is not referring to VB modules.  How would that make sense for other .NET languages?  A module is a class when compiled - equivalent to a C# static class - so you need to treat it as one when using Reflection.

Answer (score 1):

As @jmcilhinney said in the comments a Module is like a Class when using reflection. You can access it using `GetType` or `GetTypes` method.

```
Dim asm As Assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly
Dim my_module = asm.GetType("Module_Full_Name")
Dim allMethods = my_module.GetMethods()
```

Answer (score 0):

Module in VB.NET is nothing else than static class. You not create instance of static class, just call its members from anywhere in scope where module is declared.

```
Public Module Mathematics
  Public Function Sum(x As Integer, y As Integer) As Integer
    Return x + y
  End Function
End Module

Class Form1
  Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    Dim result = Mathematics.Sum(1, 2)
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I need access to all of the functions (as a collection) - hence the reflection tag.